# Combine multiple columns based on unique cell values

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, unique

I have a sheet as so :

```
       Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4   ------ Col5 --------
ROW 1   A     C     D     T     12,26,56,58,84,96
ROW 2   J     K     K     L     56,89,105,85,96,125
ROW 3   Y     I     X     O     5,10,60,90,85,125,40
 .
 .
 .
 .
```

I need to combine two rows at a time, I am running a nested loop through the sheet, and everytime a condition is met, the two rows are combined toghether.

The condition is : the two rows shouldnt share a smilar number in Col5, in other words, for the condition to be true, "Col5 for row X" and "Col5 for row X+1" should all have unique numbers.

like this

ROW 1 & 2 returns false as they have 56 in common
ROW 1 & 3 returns true as they have no numbers in common
ROW 2 & 3 returns false as they have 125 and 85 in common

If "True" the condition is met and the rows are combined, the "false" is returned then the code moves to the next row.

What is the best way to check that the two cells have unique / not duplicate numbers ?

What I tried so far :

Until now, the set of numbers in Col5 was small, so i just used logical statment " Num1 <> Num2 AND Num1 <> Num3 AND ......
but as the numbers grows it is not possible to use that method.

I've been thinking in either :

- Make the two Col5 cells as a dynamic array, and check if the array has unique values ( not sure how to do it )
- in each Col5 cell, power each number to 2, and then sum all the numbers together, getting then one number which i can compare to the other Col5 cell number. But i am not sure if the equation can make a unique number out of that set of numbers every time ( i hope that make sens )

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have you tried on your own? And based on your example, can you show what do you mean by `two rows should not have similar numbers in the last row`? and what is considered as `unique / not duplicate`? Perhaps provide another row or 2 more to explain them.

Comment: What did you try by your own? The, your question is not clear, even if somebody will try helping braking the rule which states that you must prove that tried/did something by your own. What does " combine multiple rows together based on conditions" mean? What would you like such a code returning? What does "two rows should not have similar numbers in the last row" mean? "two cells have unique / not duplicate numbers" simple means to not be equal. The Unique concept has a meaning in case of more values of the same range...

Comment: I edited my post, i hope i made my question a little bit more clear, and it makes sens now.

Comment: To make an array out of the contents of Col 5, use the `SPLIT` function.  To tell if they are unique, iterate through them storing in a Dictionary, Collection or ArrayList object.

Comment: "ROW 1 & 3 returns true as they have no numbers in common" ? What about 85 ? How are the rows combined ? is col5 expanded to both sets of numbers ?

Comment: @CPD1082 : The was a random exempel, so replaced the 85, so all numbers are unique. And yes the rows are combined, in a way that col5 is expanded to both sets of numbers

Comment: @RonRosenfeld ... thanks that is a good suggestion. I am running af permutation loop, so for every permutation, i should populate 2 arrays, one for every Col5, combine the 2 arrays and then check that the set only contain unique numbers ? .. correct understood ?

Comment: @mounim The best way to do that depends on if you have to test each array for uniqueness separately and what you might do if a single array of numbers is not unique.  If that is not an issue, then just add each array of numbers to the object one at a time.  If all are unique, then just create your resultant Col5 from the object.

Comment: What is the max number in Col5 ? How many rows approx ? If rows 1 and 3 are combined does row 1 col1 become AY, col2 CI, col3 DX and col4 TO and row 3 is deleted ?

Comment: So, you want iterating to compare each value (split by comma) of `Col5' and consider `False` if there are common numbers between the analyzed cells and `True` if not. Now, how to you want such a code to return? Something like 1-2 = False, 1-3 = True, 2-3 = False? If so, where this evaluation to be outputted? In an array or how? If not, what kind of returning do you expect/want/need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, test the next code. It process the 5th column ("E:E"), returns an array as I suggested in my comment and its content is dropped in colun "G:G", starting from the second row:

```
Sub comopareRows()
   Dim sh As Worksheet, lastRow As Long, arr, arr2, arrChk, arrC
   Dim mtch, i As Long, arrFin, j As Long, k As Long
   
   Set sh = ActiveSheet
   lastRow = sh.Range("E" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
   arr = sh.Range("E2:E" & lastRow).Value 'place the range in an array for faster iteration
   ReDim arrFin(1 To WorksheetFunction.Combin(UBound(arr), 2), 1 To 1): k = 1
   For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        arrChk = Split(arr(i, 1), ",")
        For j = i + 1 To UBound(arr)
            arr2 = Split(arr(j, 1), ",")
            mtch = Application.IfError(Application.match(arrChk, arr2, 0), "##") 'it replace the not mathing error with "##"
            If UBound(Filter(mtch, "##", False)) = -1 Then        'it eliminates the error replacement string and counts remained elements (in base 0)
                                                                  'an empty array returns -1
                arrFin(k, 1) = i & "-" & j & " = True": k = k + 1
            Else
                arrFin(k, 1) = i & "-" & j & " = False": k = k + 1
            End If
        Next j
   Next i
   'drop the result:
    sh.Range("G2").Resize(UBound(arrFin), 1).Value = arrFin
End Sub
```

Please, test the code and send some  feedback.

I tried commenting the lines which looked more difficult to be understood. If something still unclear, please do not hesitate to ask for clarifications.

Comment: @mounim Didn't you find some time to test the above code? If tested, didn't it do what you need?

Comment: Thanks you, it do what i actually need :)